# Add widget in template (magento)

Tags: magento, widget

I want to add widget support in porto template, because them said that the widget is not supported in the theme, how I can do? I tried to search here and in Google, but I didn't find how i can do. there is some code to add in template for have compatibility with all the widget?

Comment: Removed non-English content as this is an English-only site. Other language mirrors are named eg. es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?